# What can I do to solve the error for argument 'Cannot parse arguments with no order'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I think the issue is on:

```
    result = CoordinateRow([])
```

When I debug it I get a Returns None error.

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 60, in <module>
    interlaced_rows = get_interlace_rows(splits_file)
   line 49, in get_interlace_rows
    previous_row = previous_row.interlace(row)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'interlace'
```

New error after un-indenting return result (in class CoordinateRow):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 29, in __getattr__
    return self[item]
  line 25, in __getitem__
    return self._dict[item]
KeyError: 'calculate_new_coord'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 59, in <module>
    get_new_coordinates(interlaced_rows)
  line 54, in get_new_coordinates
    new_coordinates = current_coordinates.calculate_new_coord()
  line 32, in __getattr__
    "'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(type(self).__name__, item)
AttributeError: 'Coordinate' object has no attribute 'calculate_new_coord'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From coordinates pypi page:

> They can be instantiated in any of the ways a dict can (from another
> Mapping, a sequence of pairs, some keyword arguments, or a mixture of
> the above).

Example:

```
Coordinate(x=1, y=2)
```

Just change this line in `get_new_coordinates` function:

```
current_coordinates = Coordinate(int(coordinate[0]), int(coordinate[2]))
```

to:

```
current_coordinates = Coordinate(x=int(coordinate[0]), y=int(coordinate[2]))
```

But, after this, your code get a `AttributeError: 'Coordinate' object has no attribute 'calculate_new_coord'`, because you use a `calculate_new_coord` method that dont exist in `Cordinate` class.

EDIT: after change the problem, appear that you dont need the coordinate module. Just remove then, use your own Coordinate class. With your class, change back this line:

```
current_coordinates = Coordinate(int(coordinate[0]), int(coordinate[2]))
```

This way, I get the expected output:

```
6,4
6,5
10,8
8,8
8,6
7,5
7,3
7,4
5,5
4,2
9,7
10,6
5,3
```

But, if you need to use the coordinates module, you need just do this:

```
def get_new_coordinates(interlace_rows):
    for coordinate in interlace_rows.row:
        current_coordinates = Coordinate(order='xy', x=int(coordinate[0]), y=int(coordinate[2]))
        new_coordinates = current_coordinates + Coordinate(order='xy', x=1, y=0)
        print('%d,%d' % (new_coordinates['x'], new_coordinates['y']))
```

In this case, you you need to remove or rename your Coordinate class.

Comment: You completly change the problem while I public my answer! hehehe

Comment: Your traceback is about a code that isn't in description. This way I cant help. And the error before you edit the description was another (with relation with the question title). If you put the error or errors (what you are editing that change the error) with the code is associate with maybe I can help.

Comment: calculate_new_coord doesn't exist. Or you expand the coordinate class and add the method or you do a function and pass the instance. I dont know what you want with this function.

Comment: I added my code in the question and updated the error that I get.

Comment: There is a ident problem with the return of interlace method (of class CoordinateRow). The return is inside a IF statement. Because this, you are getting None as return. Just remove four spaces before the "return result".

Comment: I took out the indent and a new error popped up, I put that new error in the question, take a look and tell me what you think.

Comment: You have two class Coordinate: from coordinates module and your own class. In the first the constructor is like a dict object. Your own class get directly the values of x and y. I think there was a conflict with this classes in your code, first you are using the module class like you code your class and vice versa.

Comment: Would you mark my answer as "correct"? I will be happy.